# Ubuntu from USB stick won't work

Tags: installation, usb, live-usb, cursor

I'm relatively new to linux and am trying to put linux my HP netbook. Since I'm trying to install it on a netbook I have to use the USB method of partitioning my hard drive.

So I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and put it on to my USB drive with various different live USB creators, LinuxLive USB creator, and unetbootin for example and all arrive at the same issue. After the live USB has been created I power down and then start up my computer and go to BIOS and tell it to load from the USB instead of the hard drive and it displays about two lines that seem like copyright information, but it's hard to tell they are on screen for about 2 seconds and then the screen goes blank and a flashing cursor (_) is in the upper left corner. I've left it here for about an hour thinking it might be slow but nothing has changed.

I thought it might be the USB that was the issue so I put it in another computer (laptop but not netbook) and that booted up and loaded the Ubuntu menu just fine, so my thought is that the problem stems from it being a netbook.

I don't get to any ubuntu menu at all so I can't change any settings, so I am at a loss for what to do. Any ideas?

EDIT: some System Specs: Model: HP Mini 210-2000, Processor: Intel Atom CPU N550, 2 gb RAM Display adapter: Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3150.

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: What is the model and specs of your HP netbook?

Comment: Model: HP Mini 210-2000, Processor: Intel Atom CPU N550, 2 gb RAM Display adapter: Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3150, Any other info you would like?

Comment: Do you have another usb Drive to try it out , please try so. Because it seems a H/W problem or a BIOS config.

Comment: I don't have another USB to try it on but I don't think that it's the USB since I can load Ubuntu through that USB on a different computer. I'm guessing that means the problem is my hardware then?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your BIOS.
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4247645&taskId=135

Edit: Intel Atom is *not* an ARM processor. If this were the case, it could not have shipped with Windows 7.

Comment: You're correct. My mistake about Atom being ARM based. I deleted my answer.